# Setting Quantity Field on Subscriptions

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2

### *How can I pass in a quantity value while creating a subscription?*

---

**Plugin (version):**

- **Craft CMS** (3.1.21)
- **Craft Commerce** (2.1.2)
- **Stripe for Craft Commerce** (1.2.0)

---

**Problem:** My website allows users to subscribe to meal plans. For example, a user can subscribe to receive 5 vegetarian meals per week. Another user may also subscribe to recieve 10 meals per week. Currently, I must create two subscritpion plans on Stripe and on Craft (i.e Vegetarian-5 and Vegetarian-10). **Stripe's API** offers the ability to create a single plan that [charges per quantity](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/quantities) (i.e I want to create one Vegetarian Plan and charge $10 per meal).

I wrote a **plugin** that uses **createSubscription()** from [craft\commerce\services](https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/api/v2/craft-commerce-services-subscriptions.html#public-methods). However, ideally I want to send a quantity value but after reviewing Craft's logic for this function, I am unable to figure out a way to pass in a **quantity** value. However, I could easily bypass Craft and use the Stripe's API to do this ([setting subscription quantity through stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/quantities)) but that feels like the wrong solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realize that this is an older question, but I have found the answer for it after much searching, and want to leave this answer for others who might be coming from a search engine.

The way I have found that you would do this is with the Stripe Payments plugin. The documentation for it can be found at https://github.com/craftcms/commerce-stripe.

From there, you will find that there is a beforeSubscribe event. You can use that to set parameters for quantity. From the documentation:

```
use craft\commerce\stripe\events\SubscriptionRequestEvent;
use craft\commerce\stripe\base\SubscriptionGateway as StripeGateway;
use yii\base\Event;

Event::on(StripeGateway::class, StripeGateway::EVENT_BEFORE_SUBSCRIBE, function(SubscriptionRequestEvent $e) {
    $e->parameters['someKey'] = 'some value';
    unset($e->parameters['unneededKey']);
});
```

For my subscription, I have found that `$e->parameters['items'][0]['quantity'] = 3;` works for my setup.